# Should I use Java 8's Optional in my wrapper class or null when not using some attributes?

Tags: java, wrapper, option-type, optional-parameters

I wrote a Wrapper class for few a strings.

```
    public class StringsWrapper { 
        private String name;

        private String surname;

        private String socialSecurity;


        public StringsWrapper()
        {
            name = null;
            surname = null;
            socialSecurity = null;
        }
    //getters and setters
    ...}
```

There are three scenarios:

- I will set only name and surname, leaving `socialSecurity = null`
- I will set only surname and socialSecurity, `leaving name = null`
- I will set only surname, `leaving name = null` and `socialSecurity = null`

My question: would be preferable to use null when an attribute it's not needed or should I use maybe instances of Java 8's `Optional`?

Comment: Use null. The purpose of `Optional` is as a return value from certain methods, not to be stored in a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to point out the fact that some of these are nullable, and the rest of the code  makes use of streams/optionals etc., you can make the getters return optionals:

```
Optional<String> getName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(name);
}

Optional<String> getSurname() ...

etc.
```

You shouldn't have actual field types as `Optional`s. One reason being these are not serializable.

But generally the use case you described is probably more suitable for some `boolean` discriminatory method like `isSocialSecurityProvided()` that you can later use like this:

```
if (sw.isSocialSecutiryProvided()) {
    // do something with
    sw.getSocialSecurity();
} else {
    //do domething with
    sw.getName();
    // and with 
    sw.getSurname();
}
```

Even if the whole method looks like something below, one could argue that naming it properly provides better readability of the code:

```
public boolean isSocialSecurityProvided() {
    return socialSecurity != null;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to elaborate on why having a separate discriminatory method is better than having one method that returns Optional?

Comment: It's not 'better', it's "might be more suitable" to keep the codebase 'aligned'. If the rest of it doesn't make any use of 'functional' stuff, this gonna stick out like sore thumb.  On the other hand, maybe this is hte opportunity to switch all of it to streaming and optionaling? Who knows? But if they're asking, probably the codebase doesn't do that much, b/c we wouldn't have a SO question. So not stricte better/worse - just one of these decisions you need to make in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use null for this case and you can change it in the future